# How to construct regex for preg_match in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

- Password must be atleast 8 characters long
- Passwords must start with “a” and end with “2”
- Passwords must contain atleast two numbers and a special character(- _ *)

As far as I've gotten is that I need to be using

```
preg_match("^a 2$ ?<\d", $string)
```

The order and meeting the rest of the requirements I cannot seem to get right. What would the regex look like?

Comment: Read up on regular expressions basics (google it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=(.*?\d){2})(?=.*?[-_*])a.{6,}2$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/jX3uY5

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using some `if` statements to check each of the condition separately. If any statement fails you can cancel further checking. Only last two conditions are regexp. This way you can control the error handling and e.g. let the user know what exactly is wrong:

```
$string = '...';

if (strlen($string) < 8) {
    // too short
}

if ('a' !== substr($string, 0, 1)) {
    // first character not "a"
}

if ('2' !== substr($string, -1)) {
    // last character not "2"
}

if (2 > preg_match_all('/\d/', $string)) {
    // less than 2 numbers
}

if (1 > preg_match_all('/[-_*]/', $string)) {
    // no special characters (-_*)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^(?=(.*?\d.*\d))(?=.*?[-_*])a.{6,}2$
```

Answer (score 0):

Matches this

```
 #  ^(?=\D*\d\D*\d)(?=.*[-_*])a.{6,}2$

 ^ 
 (?= \D* \d \D* \d )
 (?= .* [-_*] )
 a .{6,} 2
 $
```